# Latex command with line break

Tags: latex, command

I am trying to create a command in latex that, when invoked such as
`\test{\ab}{TEST}`, will create a new command defined as
`\ab[1]{\raggedright TEST: \\ \hspace{0.5in} #1}`.

What I am trying to do is something along these lines:

```
\newchar{\ab}{TEST}
\ab{This is a line TEST says.}
```

That would execute to yield

```
TEST:
     This is a line TEST says.
```

Failing that (which I do hope is possible), I could settle with another command I have drafted.  But the issue there is I need a way to place and newline after the text without the user having to specify it.

Thanks ahead for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command definitions can be nested; double the `#` for each level.

```
\newcommand\newchar[2]{%
  \newcommand #1 [1] {%
    \raggedright #2: \\ \hspace{0.5in} ##1%
  }%
}
```

---

*Update:* Just a comment about the `#` doubling. This makes more sense when you're defining macros using the `\def` primitive; in this case, the general construction is something like

```
\def\foo{%
  \def\bar##1{bar: ##1}%
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Funny, nowhere on the internet did I see the part about double #'s for each level.  Thanks!

Comment: Now that I understand the questions, I was just about to suggest trying that. Another day, another thing learned. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not completely clear to me, but perhaps:

```
\newcommand{\ab}[1]{\\
#1:\\
\hspace{4em}This is a line #1 says.}
```

is a place to start (in particular, your horizontal spacing needs need to be made clearer).

[Helpful link.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX)

Comment: That works as the formatting. But I am looking for a way to have a command that can create new "aliases" of that. Such that I can have "\test" and call that a few times to create "\ab1" "\ab2" "\ab3" (The name determined by what it is "\test" is passed). Sorry if I am not being very clear, this is somewhat difficult to explain :S